Object Identification

I’m sure a lot of folks post pictures of objects asking for identification but this one has myself (astrophysicist) and my peers a little stumped. This picture was taken outside Saskatoon, CA on 10/15/24 at 06:29 local time. I think it’s north facing based off lighting and the two stars I can see but not certain. I looked for rocket launches but couldn’t find anything that matched up with the time and location. It supposedly didn’t move but disappeared after a while (this could’ve just been it getting lighter). Any guesses are much appreciated!

There is, of course, a comet (A3) visible now, but wrong time and wrong part of the sky. It was visible in the west in the evening.  So this could be an airplane contrail of some kind. What's going on in the foreground?  Did you take the photo yourself?

Sometimes a plane's headlights (yes, they do have them) can light up what's ahead of them, but this is usually only seen when there's thin wispy cloud (etc), whereas your pic indicates a crisp clear sky.

The foreground are sheared wheat stalks with some geese decoys, I though it might have been some side lit contrail or cloud or other but it has such a unique profile I wasn’t sure.

Contrail is my best guess, going almost directly away, lit by dawn that hasn't quite reached you yet, but that's an impressive photo. I woulda sworn it was A3 if it wasn't the complete wrong direction.
